# How to get Netcredentials object from logged in user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to hit a url which accepts username and password to authenticate. But this username and password should be currently logged in user credentials.

how can i acheive this? Here is my code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxx") as HttpWebRequest;

request.Credentials = This should be credentials of Windows Logged in user.

request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at LDAP, this will allow you to authenticate a username and password against a Windows active directory account. See: [How to authenticate against the Active Directory by using forms authentication and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340)

Comment: where does Active Directory comes in?

Comment: I said Active Directory because as far I as I know that's the best way to authenticate a username and password against a Windows account over the internet. Even if you could get the credentials of the logged in user using the method above you would not be able to read both their username and password to compare against. You would also most likley pick up the IIS_USER account rather than the user account.